# Tidy expression for polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, approximation-theory

I want to find a nice tidy algebraic form for the equation of this polynomial:
[image]

It has degree 6, double roots at $x=\pm1$, and it oscillates between $-1$ and $+1$.

Clearly it has the form $f(x) = c(x-1)^2(x+1)^2(x^2-k^2)$ where $k$ is the zero that's roughly $0.32$, and $c$ is an unknown constant. So, all I really need is a nice tidy expression for $k^2$. All my attempts have failed -- I get a mess of surds that my rusty algebra skills cannot handle.

Since $f(0) = -1$, we have $-1 = -ck^2$, so $c = 1/k^2$, which means that $k$ is the only unknown.

If it helps, the numerical value of $k$ is approximately 0.325411344339772081233.

Motivation (if you need some): these kinds of polynomials show up as error functions in certain types of approximation problems.

**Edit:**
The best I can do is
$$
k^2=\frac{-3+2 \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}-1}+3 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^{2/3}}{2
   \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}-1}}
$$
Any hope of simplifying that??

Comment: Sure that $k$ is uniquely defined with the given informations ?

Comment: I think so. I found $k$ numerically, as you can see. I don't think I used any assumptions beyond the ones I listed.

Comment: We should have $f(0)=-1$, but this means $k^2=1$, because $f(0)=(0-1)^2(0+1)^2(0-k^2)$.

Comment: I would say it has the form $f(x) = \color{red}a(x - 1)^2(x + 1)^2(x^2 - k^2)$.

Comment: Then please work out how you found $k$ , I do not see how you did this.

Comment: @TheoBendit. You're right. Sorry. I will fix the question.

Comment: @Peter. Find the value $x = z$ where the max occurs, as a function of $k$. Then the equation $f(z)=1$ can be solved to get $k$.

Comment: $4(k^2-1)^3=-27k^2$, then $k^2-1$ is root of $4t^3+27t+27=0$. Then $k^2=1+\frac{3}{2}\left(a-1/a\right)$, where $a=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}-1}$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu. Thank you. That's better than my mess. Any way to simplify $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}-1}$?  I was thinking of trying to find $p$ and $q$ such that $(p+q\sqrt2)^3 = \sqrt2-1$. Do you think that would lead anywhere useful?

Comment: This would give nothing more simple than $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}-1}$. Another form for $k^2$ is $k^2=1-3\sinh \left(\frac13 \mathop{\rm{arcsinh}} 1\right)$